# apply patch to webform module return error

Tags: drupal, webforms, patch

I’m using Drupal 8 and webform module Version: 8.x-5.8 I want to use
**Webform Submission Change History module**
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_submission_change_history
 I install it, and I upload the patch to webform module folder as the documentation mention ->
`If you are using Webform 8.x-5.0-rc30 or after: 8.x-2.x and this webform patch`
then run
`git apply -v 2972498-9-webform-8.x-5.x-log-changes.patch`
I get the following error
`error: corrupt patch at line 72`
any suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may no need to use the patch as reported on the link that you provided:

> 8.x-5.0-rc30 or after: 8.x-2.x and this webform patch
>
> 8.x-5.0-rc29 or before: 8.x-1.x and this webform patch

You're past version 5.0-rc29/30 of the webform module, you're using 5.8

Comment: I get the following message in the "edit" page ```Make sure to patch the Webform module as explained in the README.md file of the webform_submission_change_history module.``` I think I still need to upload the patch.